# Transfer ListView with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to fill ("calculate") a ListView in a Loading Activity and when it's ready, start the new Activity with the ListView filled. So I don't have to wait to fill it in the second activity. I already have the code to fill it, but it's in the second activity.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not really possible. You cannot readily transfer widgets or adapters to another activity.

Second, this is not really necessary. Creating a `ListView` is fairly cheap. If you are experiencing performance anxiety, use Traceview to determine where the problem is, then scope your plan to deal with the problem. For example, perhaps it is your model data, not the `ListView` itself, that you need to load in advance. Or, perhaps you just need to move some work to background threads, such as loading images to go into the `ListView` rows.

Third, if these two bits of UI are this closely coupled, they should not be separate activities, but rather one activity. Whether you use fragments, or hide/show widgets, or whatever, is up to you.

Comment: It isn't slow now, because I'm using fake data just to test the app. but I'll have to access DB and more stuff, and at that time, it will be slow(I think). So i want to do everything in the first activity and show it in the second one. The second activity doesn't need to access anything, just show what the first one accessed

Comment: @user2779199: "it will be slow(I think)" -- loading your model data may take time, and there are patterns for dealing with that. That is not the same as "fill ("calculate") a ListView in a Loading Activity and when it's ready, start the new Activity with the ListView filled".

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is to transfer the data from one activity to another activity. Instead of passing the "ListView", you should be passing the data that you need to populate in the other activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("SOME_KEY", mySerializableData);
startActivity(intent)
```

You can pass any type of [`serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) data using intents.

So you should ideally:

- Create your adapter somewhere outside of your `CurrentActivity` and
  `OtherActivity`
- Pass the `mySerializableData` from `CurrentActivity` to `OtherActivity`
- Use the same adapter to populate the ListView using the data passed in the intent using `getIntent().getSerializableExtra()`
- Use `instanceof` to ensure that what getExtras() returned is of the type `MySerializableData`

So for example if we want to pass a `ArrayList<MySerializableData>`

```
Object obj = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("SOME_KEY");
if (obj instanceof List) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: However, a `ListView` is not `Serializable`.

Comment: Yes very well said, and I am not suggesting that either.

Comment: how the intent.putExtra knows that I want to pass the ListView data? with the serializable data ? Untill now I only used intent to change the activity, I don't know nothing of this things. Thanks

Comment: @user2779199 You can do `instanceof` to ensure that it is a the kind of data you sent, an ArrayList maybe

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary in the do stuff part is where I put the Adapter?

Comment: That is where you create an object of ArrayList type and cast it to `ArrayList<MySerializableData>` and then use the adapter to populate your listview with that data

Answer (score 0):

Your code for Activities, User Interface that may contain creating custom views , AND code for adapters must be independently defined or in separate packages if u prefer to go for clean coding having done that u will not face above problem and also u can REUSE your code  .